# How can i output commands from a bash script to another shell (python,root)?

Tags: bash, root

i want to open a shell of a different program from the bash script (specifically root - a software for physicists) and execute several commands in a row.

I know to enter one command:

```
echo ".L mymacro.C" | root -l
```

but i need to enter several commands one by one without closing the root shell (root is not a root user, but an interactive shell for a different program)

I have tried with the parentheses, but it didn't succeed:

```
(echo ".L mymacro.C"; echo "myClass a";echo "a.Loop") | root -l
```

I need those 3 commands entered in a root shell one by one:

```
mymacro.C
myClass a
a.Loop
```

How could i do this from a bash script?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps a [here document](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document#Unix_shells) might work:

```
$ root -l <<EOF
.L mymacro.C
myClass a
a.Loop
EOF
```

Comment: Definitely better than my answer, I like how you added a link to Wikipedia's here document page.

Comment: @ShellFish: thanks. I'm not sure that this is actually correct because, if it does work, the OP's bracketed expression `(echo ".L mymacro.C"; echo "myClass a";echo "a.Loop") | root -l` should also work.

Comment: Good point, I'll guess we'll have to wait for the OP to reply then! Although we know from experience that this can take a while.

Answer (score 1):

Can you not simply do:

```
echo -e ".L mymacro.C\nmyClass a\na.Loop" | root -l
```

This will send the data line by line to the root shell.

Or if you really want to do it one by one, you can always loop as follows:

*Code removed thanks to mhawke's remark*

Comment: Note that the second example might not work because `root` is started on each iteration and processes just one command. From the look of the commands, the first loads a macro, and the following commands might depend on that.

Comment: Good point mhawke, I should have been more careful here. I will update immediately, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to enclose with curly brackets. Try like this:

```
cat <<'EOF' | root -l
{
.L mymacro.C
myClass a
a.Loop
}
EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the answers, but unfortunately none of it worked for me. What worked was to create another file `run.cxx` with:

```
{
gROOT->ProcessLine(".L AnalyseSimple.C");
AnalyseSimple a;
a.Loop();
gROOT->ProcessLine(".q");
}
```

and to add `root -l run.cxx` to the bash script

Comment: Accept your own answer if it helped, it's ok - even advised - to do so!